# What's the difference between UIView's frame.height and frame.size.height?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cgrect

I don't understand what the difference is in a `UIView` between `frame.height` and `frame.size.height`. Why add `size`? For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.contentSize.height = self.view.frame.height
    scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It all started with Objective-C and `CGRect`. It only has two properties - `origin` and `size`. `size` is a `CGSize` which in turn has a `height` property. So it is common in Objective-C to get the height of a frame using:

```
CGFloat height = frame.size.height;
```

Technically, the correct solution (to get a proper, normalized height) is to use:

```
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(frame);
```

Then Swift came along and `CGRect` became a Swift `struct`. While it also has a `size` property of type `CGSize` which in turn has a `height` property, the Swift `CGRect` has a `height` property. In Swift, the two lines above become:

```
let height = frame.size.height;
```

and

```
let height = frame.height;
```

In most cases, there is no difference between the two ways to get the height of a frame. But there is a difference if the frame has a negative height.

Example:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: -40)
print(rect.height) // 40
print(rect.size.height) // -40
```

Accessing `size.height` gives the raw value used when the `CGRect` was created. Access `height` gives a normalized value of the height.

In most cases you should use the `height` property and not `size.height`. But more importantly, be consistent. The code in your question is inconsistent.

Comment: There is another big difference. `rect.height` is only a getter. To change height, you have to use `rect.size.height`.

Comment: @Sulthan Good point. I got focused on getting the height and overlooked setting the height.